# Easier database table creation with PHP

Tags: php, sql, migration, ddl

Is there any other more simple way of creating a database table?

I recently started creating wordpress plugins and I was fascinated by the easiness of creating a table or adding values to present tables.

[`Dbdelta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) is amazing, is there any other PHP classes just like that, that allows you to create tables that easy?

Comment: You have `ORM` for instance, wich is pretty handy. There are a great variety or `Object Related Mapping` classes out there, it's up to you and your needs / practices.

Comment: `echo '<table><tr><td>table here</td></tr></table>';` is pretty simple... What kind of tables are you talking about?

Comment: I never tried ORM, how does it work?

Comment: @marcB, sorry i didnt explain myself well.. When i say creating tables, i mean database tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sanest way to create, maintain and deploy database schemas I have found are migrations.
[Ruckusing](https://github.com/ruckus/ruckusing-migrations/wiki/_pages) is a decent migrations framework for PHP + MySQL. It works well for me on several large and small projects.